# ExoPlayer switching media source without black screen

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I'm using exoplayer in my project, when switching mediasource i just use

```
player.stop();
player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

This causes approx. 0.5 seconds black screen until it switches video.

Is there a way to tell exoplayer to retain last frame from previous video (instead of 0.5 sec black screen) until new video is started?

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2843 view this link

Comment: Check this one also :https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1942

Comment: thanks bro 1st linked solved my problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
simpleExoPlayerView.setShutterBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 9):

Exoplayer's developers have provided solution to this issue [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2843).

Simply add this line using your SimplePlayerView instance

```
playerView.setKeepContentOnPlayerReset(true);
```

Alternatively, you can also do this via your layout.xml file,

```
app:keep_content_on_player_reset="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm having a single instance on SimpleExoPlayer and i used to set this via setPlayer in exoplayer view with changed video url's but having blank screen when scroll back to previously played videos.

I just used **setPlayer(null)** before again setting the player in exoplayerview and the black screen issue fixed.

Comment: This worked for me! i have been having this issue for a bit now and after much trail and error in onViewDetachedFromWindow i set the player to null and then in onViewAttachedToWindow i set the player again